# GWT celltable custom column setfieldupdater not working for ListBox

Tags: gwt, celltable

I have created a custom cell that determines whether to display a `SelectionCell` or `TextCell`. In the case of a `SelectionCell` render, I am unable to get the `setFieldUpdater` method to fire.

Code below...

```
private class CustomTypeCell extends AbstractCell<String>
{
    SelectionCell selectCell = new SelectionCell(cardMnemonics);
    TextCell textCell = new TextCell();

    @Override
    public void render(
            Context context,
            String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            textCell.render(context, value, sb);
        }
        else
        {
            selectCell.render(context, "", sb);
        }

    }
}


    private class CustomTypeColumn extends Column<Object, String>
{

    public CustomTypeColumn(CustomTypeCell cell)
    {
        super(cell);
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(Object object)
    {
        return object.getStringValue();
    }
}
```

Implemented using...

```
CustomTypeCell cell = new CustomTypeCell();
CustomTypeColumn customCol = new CustomTypeColumn(cell);

customCol.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Object, String>()
    {
        public void update(int index, Object object, String value)
        {
            object.setStringValue(value);
            // perform action           }
    });
cellTable.addColumn(customCol, "Custom Column");
```

This works fine if i use a standard Column with `SelectionCell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering is not enough, you also want to delegate the event handling to the appropriate cell implementation: add your if/else construct into `onBrowserEvent`, and make sure you listen for the appropriate events in `getConsumedEvents`.
You should probably also implement `resetFocus`.

You'll probably find inspiration in the [`CompositeCell`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CompositeCell.java) code.

Comment: Thanks, after adding the getConsumedEvents and onBrowserEvent the setFieldUpdater method is called after changing the SelectionCell value.